# How to group one column and rank values by grouped totals of another column

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

**Situation**

I have a dataframe of tweets pulled from the Twitter API. Each tweet has an `author_id` parameter, and a `retweets` and an `engagements` parameter.

I'd like to group the tweets by `author_id`, as some authors have posted more than one tweet, and then rank them by the total number of `engagements` from the sum of each author's tweets.

**Example Dataframe**

| index | text | author_id | retweets | engagement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-20 | Max Muncy is great! | 100 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-03-21 | The worst Dodger is Max muncy. | 101 | 1 | 8 |
| 2022-03-24 | Max Muncy was great, but not so much now. | 101 | 1 | 4 |
| 2022-03-28 | What a fantastic guy, that Max muncy. | 102 | 4 | 5 |
| 2022-03-31 | Max Muncy, my vote for MVP. | 103 | 8 | 17 |

**What I tried**

`df01a.groupby(['author_id']).sum()`

That returned this:

| author_id | text | retweets | engagement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Max Muncy is great! | 3 | 2 |
| 101 | The worst Dodger is Max muncy.Max Muncy was great, but not so much now. | 11 | 84 |
| 102 | What a fantastic guy, that Max muncy. | 4 | 5 |
| 103 | Max Muncy, my vote for MVP. | 8 | 17 |

**Assessment**

The first thing I notice is that the `retweet` and `engagement` figures are concatenating instead of summing, and I've not been able to sort out why, as the `sum` method seems pretty straight-forward.

Thank you for any input on what I might be doing wrong here.

**UPDATE - 4/5**

Just noticed the note on datatypes so posting that here:

```
text          object
author_id     object
retweets      object
engagement    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Did you check the dtypes of the columns? It may be that those numbers are actually strings.

Comment: @le_camerone, just saw your note on datatypes. Thx, that hadn't occurred to me. I checked the dtypes and they're all objects, but aren't strings objects, as well? I'm a little confused, as I've tried `df01a.dtypes` and `dataTypeSeries = df01a.dtypes` and then `print(dataTypeSeries)` and all they're returning is `object`. From your note it sounds like these should be `int64` or `float64`, but haven't yet figured out how to display that.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the engagement column is numerical and not a string:

```
df['engagement'] = pd.to_numeric(df['engagement'])
```

From what you are saying you do not need to use `groupby` here. Simply sort by `author_id` and `engagment`.

```
df.sort_values(['author_id', 'engagement'], ascending=[True, True])
```

Comment: Thanks @le_camerone. If I don't use `groupby`, though, what will consolidate and sum all the `engagement` and `retweet` figures by `author_id`? Because some authors will post more than once, and I want to sum the total engagement each author generates, and then sort by that.

Comment: Thanks, your first comment was right. It needed converting to an integer, which I did and that fixed the groupby concatenation issue. Next, I convert the columns to integers with: `cols = ['retweets', 'engagement']
df01a[cols] = df01a[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)`, and then run `df01a.groupby(['author_id']).sum()` to group the `engagement` and `retweet` values by `author_id`. However, when I run that and view the dataframe, I lose the `index` and 'text' columns. I don't see why the `groupby` method I'm running is eliminating those columns.

Comment: Because you can't `sum` strings, only numbers. It will remove all non number columns I think.